# ISA Server 2006 web publish issue

Tags: iis, isa-server, web

I want to use ISA Server 2006's web publish feature to publish my internal IIS server web site (http://testorder) to a part of my external web site (http://www.mycorp.com/testorder), and currently, I met with 2 issues during my planning phase,

1. I am not using Windows domain (or Active Directory managed domain), which means I do not want to put both ISA server and the internal web server into a Windows domain (or Active Directory managed domain). I heard we have to put both ISA server and the internal web server into a Windows domain (or Active Directory managed domain) in order to use the web publish feature of ISA Server 2006, is that true?
2. Is there a guide about how to publish web site through ISA server 2006 in a step by step way? I only need most basic configurations.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Regarding ISA books, have a look at http://www.isaserver.org/pages/books.asp.  Tom Shinder is considered one of the leading guys in ISA land and his books are quite good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer that ISA Server is installed onto does not have to be a member of an Active Directory domain. Computers hosting services that are "published" through ISA Server (like web sites) also do not have to be members of an Active Directory domain (or, indeed, even running Windows-- you can "publish" a Linux-based web server just fine, for example).

It's not a "step-by-step" reference, but I strongly advise you to read [Publishing Concepts in ISA Server 2006](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb794758.aspx) from Microsoft TechNet. You really need to understand how ISA's "Publishing" model works to make it do what you want. Once you understand how it works, you won't need a "step-by-step" guide because it will "just make sense".

These ISA Server [Virtual Labs](http://www.microsoft.com/Forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/virtual-labs.aspx) may help you, too, since they guide you through some basic ISA server administration tasks.

Comment: Thanks Evan, if I have further questions, I will ask there. Thanks for your help! I have marked your reply as answered. BTW: could you recommend a book about ISA server?

Comment: I don't have any experience with books about ISA Server, unfortunately, so I can't give a personal recommendation. I'd lean toward boots from O'Reilly & Associates or APress, but I don't know if either of them have books on ISA Server. Everything I know about ISA Server I acquired from playing with it in a lab, using it in the field, and reading the Microsoft product docs.

Comment: So cool! Evan, appreciate if you could recommend me some good discussion forums for ISA Server?